# How do I insert data into the table in the module installation process?

Tags: magento2, database

I created a new extension where a table was set up in the database. I would like to offer this new module but with pre-existing data in this table.

What is the correct way to do this process?

Answer (score 4):

You can create data installer file `InstallData.php` in `Setup` folder of your module which runs after `InstallSchema.php` present in your module. Here is one possible example of InstallData.php

```
<?php 
namespace Magefan\Blog\Setup;

use Magefan\Blog\Model\Post;
use Magefan\Blog\Model\PostFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Post factory
     *
     * @var \Magefan\Blog\Model\PostFactory
     */
    private $_postFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magefan\Blog\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magefan\Blog\Model\PostFactory $postFactory)
    {
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Hello world!',
            'meta_keywords' => 'magento 2 blog',
            'meta_description' => 'Magento 2 blog default post.',
            'identifier' => 'hello-world',
            'content_heading' => 'Hello world!',
            'content' => 'Welcome to <a target="_blank" href="http://magefan.com/" title="Magefan - solutions for Magento 2">Magefan</a> blog extension for Magento&reg; 2. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!',
            'stores' => [0]
        ];

        $this->_postFactory->create()->setData($data)->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I setup Setup/InstallSchema.php, but magento will create the db table but won't detect InstallData.php, any  ideas as why it is?

Comment: +1 This... All post says that just create a new file InstallData.php in setup folder but for me, it does not even run. I delete the row in the setp_module table, ran setup:upgrade 1k times, put an exit(); on the install method and nothing happens... Also. when enabling the module with module:enable the new row for my module in the setup_module table does not even fill the data_version column and gives an error

Comment: hello @amit, how to insert multiple records? suppose 10 rows of data//

Comment: Create `$data` as multidimensional array containing your multiple records. Then put your set data and save logic inside foreach look. Ex:  `foreach($data as $d) { $this->_postFactory->create()->setData($d)->save(); }`

Comment: @amitshree, I have created multiple tables using installschema, can we insert multiple records for each tables? how that can be done?

Comment: Yes you can. How you can do that depends on from where you want to insert them. Admin section module or by using InstallData ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find live examples in the magento modules. Just navigate to the folder Setup in a module and find classes InstallData or UpgradeData.

E.g. look into Magento Cms and find out how static pages will be added to db during Magento installation. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/InstallData.php